# Nessus: Host Discovery Scan finds no host

Tags: nessus

I am just starting my studies on pentesting and I have created a lab with Virtual Box with two VM's: a Kali-Linux machine and a Metasploitable2 machine. Their networks are both configured to be attached to Host-Only adapter and have no access to any outside network. Kali has IP 192.168.56.101 and MS2 has IP 192.168.56.102. I can ping to the other machine from both of them.

Well, that was the setup. I have installed Nessus on the Kali-Linux machine and I have created a very simple Host-Discovery policy with the template already provided in the software. I set up a scan with this policy and set up 192.168.56.102 as a target, but when I run it, no hosts are found.

I have tried some other policies and scans too, but it never seems to be able to find any host. Is there something wrong with the network configuration for my VM's?

Comment: when running into network problems in your lab, ***always*** run a packet capture on both source and destination to see what's making it through

Comment: Is there any way to run a packet capture from Metasploitable2? AFAIK it does not come with wireshark and I don't want to connect it an external network to download wireshark as it is a vulnerable machine.

Comment: You could download wireshark on a different machine and share it with Metasploitable2 or use a USB to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Check on both vms, on network configurations, if both are on the same virtual network and the virtual network card is connected.

Also do some simple connectivity tests like `ping` and `nmap`. If nothing works, test if your machine have access to any of the virtual machines and try to sniff the traffic there.

If there is no tcpdump or any other sniffer installed on metasploitable, with I presume that doesn't have any, you can download de .deb file and upload it. Install with `dpkg -i tcpdump.deb`

If nothing above works, and the packet capture show no packets, take a look into the kernel logs with `dmesg`, to see if the network card was recognised by the operating system, and check `lspci` to analyse if the network card is there.